# How to use empirical copula to calculate probabilities?

Tags: r, distribution

I have two variables, here is my data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxr1ql2lcxv2x6g/mydata.csv?dl=0
I would like to use an empirical copula to estimate probabilites for a range of values (variable pairs).

Here is what I did so far. Using pseudo observations I created the empirical copula (ec).

```
m <- pobs(mydata)
n <- 100
d <- 2
u <- matrix(runif(n*d), n, d)
ec <- C.n(u, X = m)
```

I created a matrix (variable pairs) with a range of values for which I would like to calculate probabilities.

```
v1 <- seq(from=-10, to=0, by=0.5)
v2 <- seq(from=5, to=25, by=0.5)
matrix <- matrix(nrow = 21, ncol = 41)
dimnames(matrix) = list(v1, v2)
```

When building the bivariate disribution using the mvdc function you normally need to plug in a parametric copula model as well as the parametric marginal distributions. But what if both are empirical? In other words, how can I do this with an empirical copula using empirical marginal distributions and calculate the probabilites for the given matrix?

Comment: You can make some distributional assumptions regarding your marginals and obtain their parameters by fitting. Then proceed to copula modelling. Again, you have to use some assumption for its analytic form (eg Gaussian).

Comment: @slava-kohut thanks for your feedback, but what you are proposing is fitting parametric distributions for both the marginals and the copula, I have already did that. What I would like to know is whether there is any way in R to do this using the empirical distributions for both the marginals and the copula.

Comment: I see. Check out the `copula` package (the `empCopula` class), this is a good [place](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/vignettes/empiricial_copulas.html) to start.

Comment: Why do you want a copula ? Can't you simply use the empirical multivariate cumulative distribution function ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks for your comment, actually that is what I eventually did:)